# ServiceStack SSE OnJoin and OnLeave callbacks aren't being triggered after calling SubscribeToChannelsAsync and UnsubscribeFromChannelsAsync

Tags: servicestack, server-sent-events

I have a single ServerEventsClient object that I use to dynamically subscribe and unsubscribe from channels as needed. I have some channels that are always open and that I pass in the constructor. I register to other channels by calling `SubscribeToChannelsAsync()`. The connection is actually established and I am able to communicate with the other side using it (I'm using SSE as chat), but none of our OnJoin registered methods get called. The same is true for `UnsubscribeFromChannelsAsync()` and OnLeave. I tried using the `UpdateSubscriberAsync()` and got the same results.

Worth noting is the fact that I have `NotifyChannelOfSubscriptions` set to `true` in my ServerEventsFeature.

Could the problem be in the fact that we are (un)subscribing after we initialize the ServerEventsClient object with initial channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a subscribers channels subscription is updated after they've subscribed it [fires an onUpdate event](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-server-events-client#message-events).

Comment: That notifies myself of updates that I do, but I want others to be notified of updates that I do. For instance, when I log out of the chat (unsubscribe from a channel), I want others to show a message in their chatbox that I logged out.

Comment: Right now we opted to make a new ServerEventsClient for each conversation, and OnJoin and OnLeave work for all sides.
The following problem now emerges. The other side receives message that I joined with a period equal (so we assume) to the `IdleTimeout` property again and again. Also I sometimes get OnLeave two times for the same user.

Comment: The onUpdate event is fired for all currently subscribed channels, I've just published an update that will also send it to previously unsubscribed channels as well which is now available from v5.8.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget). If you use multiple ServerEventsClients you'll receive multiple events because you're creating multiple subscriptions, i.e. it wouldn't happen if you only used a single `ServerEventsClient`.